# Collapse cells across several rows to a single column in a R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I want to perform the inverse of separate_rows(). i.e.:

```r
# Create example data
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,1,3,3,5),
                   x2 = c('A','A','C','C','E'),
                   x3 = 6:10)
data
```

Which results in

```
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  A  6
2  1  A  7
3  3  C  8
4  3  C  9
5  5  E 10
```

Somehow I expected a unite_rows() function in tidyr or dplyr to do this:

```
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  A  6,7
3  3  C  8,9
5  5  E 10
```

But I couldn't find any similar. Should I combine cels using unite()? (it seems a dirty way to go)

```r
unite(data, x2, x3, col = "x3", sep = ",")
```

Comment: What type should x3 be in the output? List or string?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, but it should be a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `base R` approach:

```
#Code
data <- aggregate(x3~x1+x2,data,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ','))
```

Output:

```
  x1 x2  x3
1  1  A 6,7
2  3  C 8,9
3  5  E  10
```

Comment: It works!! Of course as I am learning R, I would love an explanation of what "x3 ~ x1 + x2" means!

Comment: @Veronica Hi Vero. Sure. It is a formula. To the left of `~` you place the variable to be aggregated and to the right you add the variables you want to group. If you want more than one variable, you can use `+` to continue adding new variables. I hope that was clear!

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr's summarise to make a nested numerical vector (i.e, not turning the numbers into a character vector):

```
data %>% 
  group_by(x1, x2) %>% 
  summarise(x3 = list(x3))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     x1 x2    x3       
  <dbl> <chr> <list>   
1     1 A     <int [2]>
2     3 C     <int [2]>
3     5 E     <int [1]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using `dplyr`, using `unique` when you working with large data and you have duplicated values.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(x2) %>% 
  mutate(x3 = paste0(unique(x3), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()
# x1 x2    x3   
# <dbl> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 A     6,7  
# 2     3 C     8,9  
# 3     5 E     10
```